# Testing angular sub-module can't find dependency

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, angularjs-components

I'm trying to test my angular 1 (using typescript) modules, and I'm having issues with the dependencies:

These are my modules:

**app.module.ts**

```
export const appModule: IModule = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngAnimate',
    'angularMoment',
    'ngMap',
    sharedModule.name,
    componentsModule.name
]);
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
export const sharedModule: IModule = angular.module('app.shared', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngAnimate',
    'angularMoment',
    'ngMap'
]);
```

but when testing I get the error on **all** my tests, however my project runs just fine in the browser. So only the tests can't find the dependency throw erros like this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.shared due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

but when i set my shared module to:

```
export const sharedModule: IModule = angular.module('app.shared', []);
```

then it errors **only** on the tests that use external services, e.g.:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state
```

the test is as follows:

```
describe('component: bookmark', () => {
    let parentScope: any;
    let element: any;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(sharedModule.name));

    beforeEach(inject(($compile: ng.ICompileService, $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) => {
        parentScope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = angular.element(`<bookmark></bookmark>`);
        $compile(element)(parentScope);

        parentScope.$digest();
    }));
    it('should display a star', () => {
        const someAttrValue: string = findIn(element, 'md-icon').text();
        console.debug('found ', someAttrValue);
        expect(someAttrValue).toEqual('star');

    });
});
```

and my `bookmark` requires `$state`

any clue what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't importing **all** the dependencies,

The error remained the same, so when I imported `ui-router`, it still said it was missing `ui-router` while it was missing `angular-material`.